# "Most of us" or "the most of us"?

Tags: definite-articles

Isn't "the" in "the most of us" redundant?

Context:

> We all strive for safety, prosperity, comfort, long life, and dullness. The deer strives with his supple legs, the cowman with trap and poison, the statesman with pen, **the most of us** with machines, votes, and dollars, but it all comes to the same thing: peace in our time. A measure of success in this is all well enough, and perhaps is a requisite to objective thinking, but too much safety seems to yield only danger in the long run.

[Thinking as a Mountain](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Comment: One probably has to accept that it is idiomatic as people do sometimes use it.

Comment: Your cited author ([Aldo Leopold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldo_Leopold)) was born in 1887, so even though including ***the*** in such contexts was always relatively uncommon, when he was acquiring his language skills, it didn't necessarily sound [quite so "old-fashioned" as it does today.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+the+most+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20the%20most%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: (... and [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+most+of%2Cbut+the+most+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20most%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20the%20most%20of%3B%2Cc0)  shows *just* how uncommon the usage has always been.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like

> the majority of us

Also, notice the parallel construction.  This sentence *sounds* much better with "the" than without it.